# CollectionView won't be positioned to Center

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been stuck in this programming problem for a while now. I've designed a screen just like [this](https://www.uplabs.com/posts/free-psd-dark-material-statistics-page) in my Xamarin.Forms application. the part I'm stuck is centering the CollectionView which is the part in the screen where it stacks the months. I've tried using Margin but it's not the best solution because it will show different in each screen. I've tried messing with StackLayout and setting its HorizontalOptions to Center/Expand didn't work. Even when I directly set the CollectionView to Center/Expand the content of the CollectionView will still be in the "Start" align of the screen. I'm so clueless here, no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Note that this control is stacked inside a Grid.Row within the main Grid.

XAML is pasted here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Covid19Tracker.Converters;assembly=Covid19Tracker"
             xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:Covid19Tracker.Common;assembly=Covid19Tracker"
             xmlns:chart1="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Chart;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Chart"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             FlowDirection="{x:Static Device.FlowDirection}"
             BackgroundColor="#0c0e28"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             x:Class="Covid19Tracker.Views.MainView">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:FlowDirectionConverter x:Key="FlowDirectionConverter"/>
            <converters:ListMarginConverter x:Key="MarginConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
            <ScrollView>
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <!--Topbar-->
                    <Grid Padding="30">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="22" WidthRequest="22" Source="menu.png"/>

                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Margin="30,0,0,0" FontSize="24" Text="{i18n:Translate TopbarLabel}"/>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                            <Image HeightRequest="22" WidthRequest="22" Source="search.png"/>
                            <Image Margin="20,0,0,0" HeightRequest="22" WidthRequest="22" Source="options.png"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                    <!--Topbar-->

                    <!--Graph-->
                    <chart1:RadCartesianChart Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="150" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <chart1:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                            <chart1:CategoricalAxis MajorTickBackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                                                    LabelTextColor="Transparent" 
                                                    LineColor="Transparent" 
                                                    LabelFitMode="MultiLine"
                                                    PlotMode="OnTicks" />
                        </chart1:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                        <chart1:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                            <chart1:NumericalAxis MajorTickBackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                                                  LineColor="Transparent"
                                                  LabelTextColor="Transparent"/>
                        </chart1:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                        <chart1:RadCartesianChart.Series>
                            <chart1:SplineSeries 
                                Stroke="#e32049"
                                ValueBinding="Value"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding InfectionHistory}"/>
                            <chart1:SplineSeries 
                                Stroke="#2979ff"
                                ValueBinding="Value"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding RecoveredHistory}"/>
                        </chart1:RadCartesianChart.Series>
                    </chart1:RadCartesianChart>
                    <!--Graph-->

                    <!--Statistics-->
                    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FlowDirectionConverter}}" FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding Recovered, StringFormat='{}{0:0,0}'}"/>
                                <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{i18n:Translate txtRecovering}" TextColor="#2979ff"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,15,0,0" Color="#2979ff" HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="180"/>
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FlowDirectionConverter}}" FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding Infected, StringFormat='{}{0:0,0}'}"/>
                                <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{i18n:Translate txtInfections}" TextColor="#e32049"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,15,0,0" Color="#e32049" HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="180" />
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>
                    <!--Statistics-->

                    <!--Extended details-->
                    <CollectionView  
                        x:Name="CollectionView"
                        Grid.Row="3" 
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"  
                        SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={x:Reference CollectionView}}"
                        Margin="0,10,0,30"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding MonthModels}" 
                        HeightRequest="30">
                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="70"/>
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#0c0e28" />
                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                                    <Label FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding MonthLabel}">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState Name="Normal">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#4f516e"></Setter>
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    </Label>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>

                    <ListView
                            Grid.Row="4"
                            SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                            SeparatorColor="#232539"
                            HasUnevenRows="True"
                            HeightRequest="350"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            x:Name="ListView"
                            x:FieldModifier="public"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid Padding="20">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Label TextColor="White" Margin="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MarginConverter}}" Text="{Binding date, StringFormat='{}{0:MMMM dd}'}" />

                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
                                            <Image Margin="0,0,6,0" WidthRequest="6" HeightRequest="6" Source="BluePoly.png"/>
                                            <Label TextColor="#2774f5" Text="{Binding recovered, StringFormat='{}{0:0,0}'}" />
                                        </StackLayout>

                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="2">
                                            <Image Margin="0,0,6,0" WidthRequest="6" HeightRequest="6" Source="RedPoly.png"/>
                                            <Label TextColor="#e32049" Text="{Binding infected, StringFormat='{}{0:0,0}'}" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    <!--Extended details-->

                </Grid>

            </ScrollView>
        </RefreshView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I hope I filed this question properly in order to get serious help and not "read FAQ"

Comment: Do you want to let the month display in the center of screen (with space on left and right) ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Yes, exactly what i want to do ;], currently there is spacing (because of the ItemSpacing=70) but i want to align it to the Center, which is stuck in Start.

Comment: You could check my answer , is the gif achieve the effect that you want to get ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Yes, that's what i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an extra Column both on left and right of the label .

```
<DataTemplate>
  <Grid>

     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />  
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

```
<Label Grid.Column="1" FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding MonthLabel}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" >
```

Now the label will display on the center of screen

[image]

### Update

You can also put the whole CollectionView in the second

```
 <Grid>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



            <!--Extended details-->
            <CollectionView 
                Grid.Column="1"
                        //...>
                
                  //...
            </CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I swear to god I tried this and it looked much better but still isn't in center -.-"

Comment: It's like there's something about this collectionview that doesn't want to adjust itself to the center

Comment: You could set the proportion of three Columns as you want

Comment: Zhang, I know but it doesn't space well between them. If there's no other way to fix this I'll accept your answer anyways.

Comment: Or you could set two Columns with 0.5*and 0.5*

Comment: I think my solution is better than setting margin .

Comment: Sorry in my sample there  is only a CollectionView .

Comment: So in your case my first solution is better .

Comment: Is there any other control i can use in this case instead of the collectionview? look at the ui screen in the link, the month in grey.

Comment: I noticed that you binding the selected command for logic handling . In such a case collectionview is the best .

Comment: Yes sir, thanks. keep me updated if you find anything <3

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved Collection centering. You'll find it here:

[How to centre CollectionView items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970388/how-to-centre-collectionview-items/67858929#67858929)