# How to centre CollectionView items?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have the following XAML code and the intention is to centre the letter in the middle of the screen, horizontally. However, this code still places the items on the left.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Aqua" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <CollectionView BackgroundColor="Beige" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>A</x:String>
                    <x:String>B</x:String>
                    <x:String>C</x:String>
                    <x:String>D</x:String>
                    <x:String>E</x:String>
                    <x:String>F</x:String>
                    <x:String>G</x:String>
                    <x:String>H</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </CollectionView.ItemsSource>

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="20"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

How can I do that?

P.S., [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH96r.jpg) is what I am getting now and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxunH.jpg) is what I want to achieve.

Comment: `HorizontalOptions="Center"` on your `Label`.

Comment: This does not work. It'll only centre the letter inside the Label not the Labels inside the CollectionView.

Comment: no, that centers the Label inside of it's container.  However, with a Horitzontal layout I'm not sure how it determines the width of each element.  You may need to place the label inside of a layout and play with it's  HorizontalOptions and width settings

Comment: Okay, my bad. However, this is still not working. I updated the sample in my question.

Comment: Did you read the suggestions I made in my comment?

Comment: Yes, I read your suggestion and placed the Label in a StackLayout with its Orientation set to Horizontal, its HorizontalOptions to Center, and this did not change the outcome.

Comment: Try setting the bg color of the label so you can visualize how wide it is relative to it's container, and how much space exists between each label.

Comment: Here is a screen-shot after adding the background colour and StackLayout: https://imgur.com/a/wdyqIGp

Comment: Help me to understand here, because I am a bit confused. How changing the individual item is going to affect the place of all items within the CollectionView? Should not there be an option to say something between the lines of "start place the items from the middle"? In other words, playing with the CollectionView properties instead.

Comment: do you want to center each Label within it's layout, or center the overall CV contents on the page?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understood your question, but instead of [this](https://imgur.com/a/wdyqIGp) I want [this](https://imgur.com/a/jZnyAkn).

Comment: are you going to have a fixed number of columns?  Are there going to be more than 1 row?

Comment: I have 1 row but the items are variable.

Comment: HorizontalTextAlignment?

Comment: @Shaw, as a property of the Label? It will centre the text within the Label, which is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: Kind of a text wheel picker? Still not get your intention clearly, maybe have some screenshot or draw sth would help.

Comment: @Shaw, My intention is centring the labels in the middle of their container horizontally. Added screen-shots to the question.

Comment: @TheBlueSky It seems CollectionView in Xamarin Forms not supports center property for Items. Maybe you could have a try with Custom `CollectionViewRenderer` to try.

Answer (score 0):

Did some test with your code and got the boundary of the collection view as shown in the first screenshot.

So the collection is already centred, just as too few items in the list makes it look like left-aligned.

[image]

**Option 1: Fix the width.**

Add **width** to Stacklayout and set background color for the page might work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    BackgroundColor="Beige">
    <!-- Add color above -->

    <!-- Add width below -->
    <StackLayout WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Aqua" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <CollectionView BackgroundColor="Beige" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>A</x:String>
                    <x:String>B</x:String>
                    <x:String>C</x:String>
                    <x:String>D</x:String>
                    <x:String>E</x:String>
                    <x:String>F</x:String>
                    <x:String>G</x:String>
                    <x:String>H</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </CollectionView.ItemsSource>

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="20"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also set width to CollectionView, same result.

**Option 2. Set the margin**

Or you can set the margin on CollectionView (without fixing the width), oh, that's the color of stacklayout

```
<CollectionView Margin="80,0" ...
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, Shaw. I am afraid that does not work well with me because of the hard-coded margin. Although this works with a list that has the letters from A to H, it will not work when the list has fewer items, when the item is not a single letter, when using different font family or size, or ... etc. See [here](https://imgur.com/a/B32XNcJ) and [here](https://imgur.com/a/J4UXnUQ), for example.

Comment: Emmm, so you would like to have a collectionview with dynamic width, which means the collection view will always be at the center even when there is only one letter in the list. Does this suit your idea? I'm not a fan of fixed margin either, but probably could do some calculation to set the width dynamically.

Comment: I really do not care about the width of the CollectionView; all I want it to do is to start placing the items from the middle instead of from the left (or start). Looks like this is asking too much or expecting too much :) For now, I replaced CollectionView with FlexLayout until I find a better solution.

Comment: All good. Flexlayout is another option, I just assume that CollectionView suits more for a dynamic list. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: FlexLayout was not my first choice but alas, I was not able to make the CollectionView work.

Answer (score 0):

I set a fixed width to the grid inside the Datatemplate and then Bind the collectionview WidthRequest to the number of items times the fixed width.

```
 <CollectionView
            x:Name="weatherCollectionView"
            Margin="0"
            Background="Red"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            IsVisible="True"
            ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TripsWeatherCollection}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            WidthRequest="{Binding CollectionViewWidth}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="7" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout
                        Margin="0"
                        Padding="0"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        WidthRequest="300">
```

Works well, but make sure you only call it after you've established your collection and use a null check. Your fixed width will have to be a little larger in the viewmodel to account for your margin or item spacing.

```
CollectionViewWidth = 310 * TripsWeatherCollection?.Count ?? 0;
```

Comment: Where does the number 310 come from? Is this `WidthRequest` with some extra pixels?